# What triggers suicide in Gods will be Watching, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: gods-will-be-watching

*Gods Will Be Watching* is generally good about explaining what you did wrong when you die. (How was I supposed to know I needed fire to stay warm through the night?) But I recently committed suicide and I don't know why. What triggers this kill condition, and what can I do to stop killing myself?

[image: Sgt Burden failed his men and committed suicide]

Comment: That is one hell of a title when taken out of context.

Comment: I love the titles of some questions here :)

Comment: I think RPG has a *How can I tell when a corpse is safe to eat?*, and somewhere is *my head keeps falling off*.

Comment: @gerrit [indeed](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) [there](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37805/my-head-keeps-falling-off-what-can-i-do) [are](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24345/how-can-i-kill-adorable-animals)... maybe we should have a best-of meta post

Comment: The developers are doing a indiegogo campaign for a real game. http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/gods-will-be-watching Looks awesome.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/124388/2 =(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your morale counter was negative. When that happens on a crew member they go insane and leave. When you lose all of your human crew members the game ends.

Use Request Inform on BR4ND-0N. The numbers show you the mental state of you crew members. Talking to them increases morale by one for that member. Using group therapy increases morale of everyone by 2 ( or 1-3 it varies ).

The robot and dog do not have a morale counter.

Comment: I could have sworn that I lived for a few turns after killing my human crew (the robot and the dog should have sufficed, and Sarge doesn't have any morale to lose), but perhaps I was mistaken

Comment: @Sean The game always ended for me when i killed every human. Maybe there is some hidden counter.